# Copy whole table to another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkcopy

I want to insert a whole table's contents to another database which has the same table name.

How can I achieve this?

I am using SQL Server Express 2008 R2.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Answer (score 3):

you can create a table with same schema in another database first and copy the data like this. Let say my new Database name is `NewDataBase` and I want to copy data from table `Sales.SalesPerson` of `[AdventureWorks2012]` database and both database are in same server.

```
CREATE TABLE [NewDataBase].[dbo].EmployeeSales
( BusinessEntityID   varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  SalesYTD money NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO [NewDataBase].[dbo].EmployeeSales
    SELECT BusinessEntityID, SalesYTD 
    FROM [AdventureWorks2012].Sales.SalesPerson;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the Data Import/Export Wizard.